# Delete all cookies in page onUnload event

Tags: cookies

I try to use following code to delete all cookies in page unload event. However it doesn't seem to work in Chrome. Is there a better way to do it?

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var chip = cookies[i],
                entry = chip.split("="),
                name = entry[0];

            document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=' + window.location.hostname + '; path=/ ';
        }
```

Comment: Hi Luyin, what language are you using?  You may get a better response if you tag your question with the language.

Comment: Also, please can you check whether the Chrome setting "Continue where you left off" is set?

Comment: Hi Lan, thanks a lot for taking a look at it. I finally figured it out from another post. I will put answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From another post I got a hint. The cookies I want to delete has Host only flag. Therefore I can not set domain when I write cookie back. Here is a working copy.

```
ar cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var chip = cookies[i],
            entry = chip.split("="),
            name = entry[0];

        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/ ';
    }
```